# Mongodb Ref dynamic populate with grapqhl?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, typegraphql, typegoose

I have to decide whether to populate or not according to the query request, but I don't know how to do it.

So Example

If my model User is looks like this

*below syntax is from typegoose and typegraphql*

```
class User {
    @Field()
    @prop()
    name: string;

    @Field()
    @prop(ref:"House")
    house: Ref<House>
}
```

And here is two diffent query

**Query1**

```
  user {
    name
  }
```

**Query2**

```
  user {
    name
    house {
      location
    }
  }
```

And in the resolver

```
User: () => {
   const user = UserModel.find(blahblah)**.populate("house")**

   return user
}
```

Query1 dose not need populate
but Query2 need
in same resolver!

**I want to decide whether to populate or not depending on the requirements of the query.**
I can't decide whether to populate or not without knowing what is the actual query was in resolver.

I found very similar question in stackoverflow
But there is not proper answer...
[Solving relationships in Mongoose and GraphQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483032/solving-relationships-in-mongoose-and-graphql)

Comment: no, it's not the same resolver ... it can be when optimizing ... follow some [better] tutorial

Answer (score -1):

i dont know much about graphql, but i think there is some method to get if that path is requested, so the following should work:

```
let query = Model.find(basicQuery);
if (req.path) { // replace this with graphql's method to get if the path is requested
  query = query.populate(yourPath);
}

const doc = await query.exec();
```

PS: but as an comment already noted, i think there is some better method to do this in graphql (another resolver?)